# Integral $\int_{C(0,3/2)} \frac{z^3}{1-\cos(\pi iz^2)}\,dz$ using residue theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck with this exam problem. It says : Resolve the following integral

$$\int_{C(0,3/2)} \frac{z^3}{1-\cos(\pi iz^2)}\,dz$$

Through the circumference $C(0,3/2)$

I asume we have to use the residue theorem. The poles are the $z=\sqrt{2ki}$ for any integer $k$. The ones that matters,i.e. the $z_j$ with $\operatorname{ind}\left(z_j\right)=1$ are these: 
$$z_1=0,z_2=1+i,z_3=1-i,z_4=-1+i,z_5=-1-i$$
Thank you

Comment: *Where* is the problem? int = $2\pi i$(sum of residues)

Comment: The problem is (sum of the residues). Could u explain me how to calculate the residues?the standard formula for the residues give me some troubles. The order of the poles its also not clear for me. If someone could solve it i will be thankfull

Comment: Pole of $1/f$ = zero of $f$ and the rule for the multiplicity of the zeros of an analytical function $f$ is the same that for polynomials. Simple iff $f(z_0)=0$, $f'(z_0)\ne0$. Double if $f(z_0)=f'(z_0)=0$, $f''(z_0)\ne0$... What formula for residues are you using?

Comment: Yes,  I used it for the orders of the poles. For z2=1+i,z3=1−i,z4=−1+i,z5=−1−i gives me order 2(im not sure if I did it well). For z1=0 i have troubles...  The formula I used for residues is the formula I found here (Limit formula for higher order poles) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis). The problem with the formula is the incalculable operations i have to do. Im not sure if Im using it well.

Comment: Near zero, $1-\cos(\pi i z^2)\approx (\pi i z^2)^2/2$. And you have a $z^3$ in the numerator.

Comment: Thank you for that, then the order of z1=0 is 1, and then I can calculate the Res(f,0). Now I just have troubles with the others Res. I dont know how to do... Thank you

Comment: The formula required is http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/c/1/fc16ae96cdbc7aea1023462e07d19753.png.

Comment: Actually Res(f,0)= -2/π2. I would like to have Res(f,1+i), Res(f,1-i)... Thank you

Comment: OK. But tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is the formula that Im using, but I have troubles solving the limit. Probably the problem is that the order of the poles is not 2, or just Im not be able to solve the limits. Thank you

Comment: Edit your post and show your calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The calculations are **very** nasty, indeed. Alternative idea: Laurent series. In $z_0=1+i$:
$$
-2+2\,i+6\,i\,\left(z-z_0\right)+\left(3\,i+3\right)\,(z-z_0)^2+(z-z_0)^3=
$$

$$
= z^3 = f(z)(1-\cos(\pi i z^2))=
$$

$$=\left({a_{-2}\over(z-z_0)^2}+{a_{-1}\over z-z_0}+a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+\cdots\right)
\times
$$

$$
(-4\,\pi^2\,i\,(z-z_0)^2+(-2\,\pi^2\,i-2\,\pi^2)\,(z-z_0)^3+\cdots).
$$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this will not be of almost any help for the computation using the residue theorem.

Using a simple change of variable $y=z^2$ and switching from $cos$ to $cosh$, the antiderivative is quite simple to compute and the result is $$\frac{\pi  z^2 \coth \left(\frac{\pi  z^2}{2}\right)-2 \log \left(\sinh
   \left(\frac{\pi  z^2}{2}\right)\right)}{2 \pi ^2}$$ May be, this could help you for checking your results.